Error al preparar consulta en POO PHP
Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en la programación POO en PHP y me encuentro con errores que no sé porque aparecen, cuando aparentemente, está todo bien. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar con este error que no consigo saber a qué es debido.
El objetivo del programa es llenar un select de HTML con una consulta a una tabla SQL. Lo he conseguido hacer mediante programación procedimental, pero ya os digo, con POO se me hace "bola".
El programa está constituido por 3 ficheros.
Uno de los ficheros contiene un select HTML que pretendo, como dije antes, rellenar con los datos que hay en una tabla SQL.
El segundo fichero, contiene la definición de la clase Conexion para conectar a la base de datos. Que es el código que pongo a continuación.
<?php
class Conexion {
    private $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;";
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "user";
    private $password ="1111";
    private $database = "database";
    private $char = "utf8";
    private $conectar;

    public function __construct() {
        $connectionString = "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->database.";charset=".$this->char;
        try {
            $this->conectar = new PDO($connectionString, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conectar->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Conexión realizada"; // Este mensaje se imprime solo si la conexión es exitosa
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception("Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function connect() {
        return $this->conectar;
    }

    public function xrellenarselect($consulta) {        
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conectar->prepare($consulta);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception('Error de consulta: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>

El tercer fichero es la definición de la clase Modelo con la que pretendo hacer la consulta SQL y rellenar el SELECT. Pero aquí me vuelca el error Undefinied method "prepare" en esta línea $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($consulta);
<?php
    require_once("autoload.php");

    class Modelo extends Conexion {
        private $conexion;          
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->conexion = new Conexion();            
            //parent::__construct();
        }

        public function rellenarselect($consulta) {                 
            try {                
                $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($consulta);
                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                throw new Exception('Error de consulta: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

?>


El error se debe a un problema al establecer el valor de la propiedad conexion.
Al hacer $this->conexion = new Conexion(); equivale a asignar el valor devuelto por el método __construct de la clase Conexion.
Como dicho método no devuelve nada... $this->conexion es igual a null.
Soluciones simples
Se me ocurren 2 soluciones simples:

Modificar el método __construct de la clase Modelo (no sería la mejor opción)
class Modelo extends Conexion
{
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->conexion = $this->connect();
    }
    // ... resto


Utilizar el método connect() siempre que necesites crear una consulta
class Modelo extends Conexion
{
    public function rellenarselect($consulta)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($consulta);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception('Error de consulta: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}



